# Can I install a front derailleur for my bike?

Tags: crankset, derailleur-front

I just bought a **[Micargi RD-7](http://micargibicycles.com/micargi-bicycles/road-bikes/micargi-rd/micargi-bike-rd-7)** with 7 speed Shimano Tourney rear derailleur. Now, I want to upgrade my crankset from single chainring to three chainrings for better hill climbing. Is it possible to do that? what front derailleur and crankset should I buy?

- **Shifters**          :  Shimano SL-RS35-7R/LN 3x7 Speed
- **Rear derailler**    :  Shimano RD-TX35  , 7-Speed
- **Chain**                 :KMC 1/2"x3/32

Comment: Given how much that bike costs, you should return it and buy something with a triple in the front to begin with.

Comment: Have you looked into "Mega range" cassettes and if they meet you needs?

Comment: Curiously, your specs link says "Shifters  Shimano SL-RS35-7R/LN 3x7 Speed"   which implies that it may have a front shifter control up on the handlebars already.  Does it?

Comment: If you "just" bought it, then most first-world countries require shops to offer a short 100% return window. In my country its 10 days.  By your description, you've bought a bike that is not what you wanted.  Research more and try out more before you commit to purchase next time.

Comment: I've also tweaked your question by removing "speed" and substituted "chainring"  This is not a singlespeed bike.  If I've messed up your question, please use Revert to undo my changes.

Comment: I love it how trend-following mountain bikers pay $1000 for having a single chainring in the front (SRAM, I am looking at you), while sane users attempt to upgrade to more speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say on this bike you can install any cheapest aluminum crankset, cheapest front derailleur and a friction (non indexed) shifter, where the crankset will be the most costly part (about 30$) and a few dollars for derailleur and shifter (each). So if you able to do the work byself you will end under 50$ for all that upgrade (but those should be done well), however if you want LBS to do the work it should cost about 20-30$ more (I don't really know the work costs in other than my regions).

EDIT:
As Batman mention in the comment, your BB can be too short for triple crank. If it is, the upgrade can't be done without replacing the BB too.
I didn't include tools cost in my answer.
And to get this work done you have to have appropriate knowledge.

As bikes have different width seat tube, your derailleur must fit it. If your frame tube is thin (and it looks that this frame has thin tube) you can take a little wider derailleur and put a holder plates between it and the frame. Of course you should check that the derailleur will be compatible to your crank teeth count.
It may seem difficult, but in LBS will be done easily. But you should compare it's cost, and cost of a new bike of same quality with front gears.

Comment: You need a crank puller to remove cranksets, possibly a new bottom bracket to get the chainline working and you need the FD to be mountable in place.

Comment: You will also likely to be missing cable stops, which will require clamp on one.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Yeah, I think I made a bad impulse purchase and sadly I cannot return this bike, so I'm trying to make it work for me.

Comment: @newbie_techie Consider on-selling it then.  You'll take a hit, but someone who rides only on the flat and mostly on the road might be happy with it.

Comment: @Rider_X you can just cuff the cable or use a scotch to put them in place